# Can the container type be deduced in variadic templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

In C++11/C++14,

```
template <
   typename T ,
   template <typename...> class Container_t
>
void MyFunc(Container_t<T> &data) { ... }


template <typename T>
void MyFunc2( T v ) { ... }


int main()
{
   std::vector<char> v;

   MyFunc<char, std::vector>(v);     // OK
   MyFunc(v);                        // error

   int i;

   MyFunc2<int>(i);                  // OK
   MyFunc2(i);                       // OK
}
```

I get an error with `MyFunc(v)`.

Is it possible in any way to let the compiler find out the type of the container passed to the variadic template function? I can see no problems in finding it out, as with a normal types in normal templates.

If I need to change the type of v, do I have to fix all the calls to MyFunc?

Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 (v140)

Comment: `std::vector` and other containers has `value_type` in them, no need for two types in deduction

Comment: @Hcorg - Can you show me what you mean? Thanks'

Comment: `v` is in fact of type `std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>`.

Comment: Should be able to deduct in your case, which compiler you're using?

Comment: Indeed, working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90801912a81903f1).

Comment: It looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: @KerrekSB `Container_t` isn't a non-deduced context though.

Comment: @Barry: You're right, the template itself can be deduced. Perhaps with variadic arguments to be sure: `template <template <typename ...> class X, typename ...Args> void f(const X<Args...>&);`

Comment: @KerrekSB Indeed it does [demo](http://rextester.com/VKY36217)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it required to explicitly list default parameters when using template template parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017466/is-it-required-to-explicitly-list-default-parameters-when-using-template-templat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to name the template's template arguments:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <
   typename T ,
   typename A,
   template <typename = T, typename = A> class Container_t
>
void MyFunc(Container_t<T, A> &data) { 
     std::cout << "value type = " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "allocator type = " << typeid(A).name() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "container type = " << typeid(Container_t<T,A>).name() << std::endl;
   }


template <typename T>
void MyFunc2( T v ) {  }


int main()
{
   std::vector<char> v;

   MyFunc<char, std::allocator<char>, std::vector>(v);     // OK
   MyFunc(v);                        // now ok

}
```

If you don't care about anything except the value type and the container...

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <
   typename T ,
   typename...Rest,
   template <typename, typename...> class Container_t
>
void MyFunc(Container_t<T, Rest...> &data) { 
     std::cout << "value type = " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "container type = " << typeid(Container_t<T,Rest...>).name() << std::endl;
   }


template <typename T>
void MyFunc2( T v ) {  }


int main()
{
   std::vector<char> v;
   std::map<char, int> m;

//   MyFunc<char, std::allocator<char>, std::vector>(v);     // OK
   MyFunc(v);                        // now ok
   MyFunc(m);                        // now ok

}
```

Comment: @101010 updated the answer to allow variadic args in the container.

Comment: It's worth noting the curious restrictions of this approach: The value type must be the first template parameter, and it doesn't work for things like `std::array`. That's why template template parameters are really not all that useful in this situation, and you're much better off deducing the type as a whole and getting at its traits in other ways.

Comment: @Richard, is it possible to do the same with member functions?

Comment: why do you default type template parameters of a template template parameter?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of trying to deduce container type, assume container defines what type it stores.

```
template <typename Container>
void MyFunc(Container& data)
{ 
   // all std containers defines value_type member (also reference etc.)
   using std::begin;
   using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
   value_type value = *begin(data);
  ...
}
```

Please note, that you might not need type of stored elements at all:

```
template <typename Container>
void MyFunc(Container& data)
{ 
   using std::begin;
   auto value = *begin(data);
  ...
}
```

if you want to work on std containers only (or the ones with similar templates arguments) - see [Richard Hodges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37330201/1630041) answer.

Comment: Use `using std::begin; using value_type = *begin(data);` will work with C-arrays and with extensions on non-`.begin()` capable containers.

Comment: Pretty sure @Yakk meant to not use `::value_type` at all.

Comment: D'oh, I meant `using value_type = std::decay_t<decltype(*begin(data))>;`, which extracts the value type from what the container returns directly.  but yes, `auto value=*begin(data);` works, with `using value_type=decltype(value);` if you need to use the type elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's a VC++ bug since GCC and CLANG can deduce the input template parameter. As proposed by KerrekSB in the comments a less painful work-around would be the following:

```
template<typename T, template<typename...> class Container_t, typename... Args>
void MyFunc(Container_t<T, Args...> &data) { 
  ...
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a64d0ae38f62fc42)