# Using default template parameters in variadic template template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, icc, template-templates

I have discovered that the minimal example below works on gcc and clang and even Visual Studio but it does not compile with icc.  I am trying to determine whether or not this is valid C++, but I am not able to find the relevant parts of the standard that answer my question since this is several different concepts combined.

```
// struct with multiple template parameters
template<typename A, typename B = int>
struct C
{

};

// struct that tries to use C's default second parameter without specifying it
template<typename D, template<typename E, typename ...> class F>
struct G
{
  F<D> h;
};

int main()
{
  G<char, C> i;
}
```

With icc (16.0.3), compilation gives the following error:

```
struct.cpp(12): error: too few arguments for template template parameter "F"
    F<D> h;

          detected during instantiation of class "G<D, F> [with D=char, F=C]" at line 17
```

Is this valid C++?

To me it seems like it should be, because `C` has a default value for its second template parameter, meaning that `F<D>` with `F = C` should be a valid construction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it required to explicitly list default parameters when using template template parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24017466/27678)

Comment: Have you tried ` template<typename ...> class F`?

Comment: @Yakk: that does not fix the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why this works at all when G<char, C> does not specify even the first template argument for C? I would've expected something like G<char, C<SomeType>>.

Comment: The second argument for G is a template template parameter, so we pass in a template class without template parameters.  I hope that's helpful, if not, maybe this post explains it better than I can here: http://codingcastles.blogspot.com/2009/04/things-i-didnt-know-about-c-template.html

Comment: The title of this question made me chuckle. This is like fuel for people saying C++ is too complicated.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a gcc/clang bug. This is related to the [still-open] [CWG Issue 150](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#150). The rationale provided includes:

> Default arguments are allowed for the parameters of a template template parameter, and those default arguments alone will be considered in a specialization of the template template parameter within a template definition; **any default arguments for the parameters of a template template argument are ignored**.

The template template parameter `F` doesn't have any default arguments - and the default arguments for `C` are ignored. So we should end up with an ill-formed specialization, as ICC suggests.

In the examples provided in the issue, both gcc and clang seem to implement the rule (neither allows the call to `f()` and both go through the `operator float()` path in Mark Mitchell's example.

Comment: Thanks for the link to CWG-150.  An important difference here is that we have variadic template parameters, so in this situation it is possible to have a variadic template parameter list of length zero by taking the default template parameter of `B = int`.  This is what gcc and clang appear to be doing, but not icc.  But the issue referred to in CWG-150 only applies if we were to remove the variadic template parameter list and replace it with just `typename` instead of `typename...`.

Comment: @ryan Well, this issue predates C++11 by a lot, so it won't refer to variadic templates. But it's ultimately the same concept.

Comment: Sad: can you think of a justification why they could not first apply template template arg defaults, then the default args of the source template?

Comment: @Yakk No, but I wouldn't put much weight in that.